# Alert Dialog Positive Button Issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have alert dialog initiated on button click , it had username and password , after alert dialog fired , if you press OK button , it force close and close the app ,

any help will be appreciated.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final Context context = this;
private Button button;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv1);
    tv.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.introclusion_tv2);
    tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
    tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.introclusion)));



button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

// add button listener
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialog_layoutView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog_layoutView);
        alertDialogBuilder

                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",

                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                                EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

                                if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                                    if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().toString().equals("test")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Text.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();}
                                    else{
                                        // get your custom_toast.xml layout
                                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast));

                                        // set a dummy image
                                        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image_toast);
                                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                                        // set a message
                                        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_toast);
                                        text.setText("Wrong username or password");

                                        // Toast...
                                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        toast.setView(layout);
                                        toast.show();}}}    


                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

    }

});

  }

  }
```

LOGCAT:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.demo.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

dialog_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_uname"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Possible username or password vars are null? Maybe instance on OnCreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(arg0.getContext());
```

and change

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext());
```

Your `context` variable is `null` because you initialize it before the `Activity` is created. And you don't need to create a `context` variable inside of an `Activity`. If, for whatever reason (maybe its simplicity) you want to use the variable then declare it where you are but initialize it inside of `onCreate()`

Also, inside the `onClick()` signature, I would change the variable name to something meaningful but that's not required. Like chanig

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
```

to

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

**Edit**

You also need to change these lines

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

to

```
EditText username = (EditText) dialog_layoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
EditText password = (EditText) dialog_layoutView.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

This will tell them to look in `dialog_layout`. Currently they are looking in the `layout` that you inflated with `setContentView()`

Comment: Ha, yes, silly mistake. I have fixed it in my answer. `getContext()` not `this`

Comment: Are your `EditText`s (`username` and `password`) inside your `Dialog` layout`?

Comment: and error line no.63 indicate this line :         if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {

Comment: work like charm , +1 upvote and accept , please can you help me in another point

Comment: Glad I could help. You will have to fix any other issues in there that you have like that where you inflate a separate `layout` and try to find a `View`. Yes, I can try here if its related or simple. Otherwise it should be a separate post

Comment: if i want to retrieve the  PositiveButton and NegativeButton from xml not coded in class so i will add two button to my dialog_style.xml the how my MainActivity class will be , thanks

Comment: You will retrieve them from your `layout` as you do for your `EditText`s and set an `OnClickListener` on them as you do normally for a `Button`.

Comment: i post new question , im new to android , if you can help me please thanks ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861485/alertdialog-with-positivebutton-and-negativebutton-from-xml