# Using toString() method on EditText crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my Android app, when I try to use this code:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String s = et.getText().toString();
```

my app crashes.  This event is triggered from a dialog positive click.

How can I access the text of an EditText without my app crashing?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message.  The app just crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: THe data you are setting to the String variable if null, it would crash the application. Check the value  of editText before setting it for null. It might resolve your issue.

Comment: See the bottom part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861082/alert-dialog-positive-button-issue/18861110#18861110) that is likely your issue. But it's impossible to say for sure without the stacktrace.

Comment: are you calling the "et" definition before setContentView?

Comment: I am using the 'et' definition in a function that is triggered my my dialog's onPositiveClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a couple of problems:

1. There is no such element as `editText`
2. `EditText` class is not imported.
3. The `EditText` element is empty, so the String `s` is null.

Here are a few ways to find the actual problem:

1. Use an IDE like Android Studio. It reports many small problems right then and there.
2. Review your code carefully and make sure it accounts for any possible situations.
3. Set up `System.out.print` statements throughout to better log the variable values and other properties.